Comic about a pair of brothers who share the same body but have different heads, the "elder" of which is eventually cut/killed in a surgery
I first read this comic 4 or 5 years ago and I think it was created no earlier than 2016.
The story is about a baby who was born with two heads. Although the two heads share the same body, their minds are separate, and they interact with each other via verbal communication. They care for each other like no one else does, but the "older" brother is much more aware of the situation. During their conversations, he always reassures his "younger" brother that everything will be fine. The "younger" brother believes him, thinking that they will eventually have their own bodies.
Eventually, they go through a surgery. When the "younger" brother wakes up, he sees himself with a complete body of his own, but his brother is nowhere to be found. As people celebrate the successful surgery, the "older" brother's head lies quietly on a tray in the darkness, covered by a piece of white cloth.
The comic itself was black and white. The author has a characteristic art style which makes use of many round shapes, especially for characters. They are also known for their many tragic stories.

This feels a lot like an EC Comics story, but that would of course be earlier.

Was that written in English, was it a translation? Did you read that in print or online? If online, was it on the artist's site/Tumblr/DeviantArt etc, or was it a scan of a printed comic? You say the author wrote other tragic stories and has their artstyle - do you know that because you were told so, or did you read them yourself and can describe a couple?

@Jenayah I read a fan-translation of it online, but I'm sure the original language is English (or Japanese, but the chance is much lower). I also read other works from the same source, which is now no longer available.

I can't remember anything about the other works though.

Does the story have any fantastical or science-fictional elements?

@user14111 These are all the details I could remember. If some of them appear fantastical or science-fictional to you, then yes.

"a characteristic art style which makes use of many round shapes, especially for characters" ‐ My immediate first thought was Chris Ware, but I don't know if he ever wrote anything like this. If he did, I can't find it.

@MJ713 Nope, not Chris Ware. It should be emphasized that the art is more or less manga-oriented (though I never knew the author's nationality).

It was Elimination by Avogado6 (2017).
I found the author's name in one of my old files.
Transcribed story (translation courtesy of Ryn):

(The two brothers sitting on a bench)
Younger brother: I'm glad I'm being removed from this body.
Older brother: For me, it suits me as we are now.
(In front of the surgery room)
People: (surrounds them) Good luck! Everything will be fine.
Older brother: (energetic) Thank you very much!
Younger brother: (almost whispering) Yeah...
(During induction of anesthesia)
Younger brother: I'm sorry I was not a good brother. I'm not smart. I'm not cute. Because of me, your movement is limited. I'm just a bother...
Older brother: (smacks his brother on the head) They will split our body in two. From now on, we will be two full people. (stops for a short while) Okay?
Younger brother: Yeah...
(Younger brother wakes up)
People: (surrounds him) How are you feeling? We are happy to see you. The elimination of your second head was a success. You are normal now. Congratulations.
The younger brother gazes at his hands. He smiles. His tears start to roll as the surrounding voices fade into the void. In the adjacent room, the older brother's head lies quietly in a tray, covered by a piece of white cloth.


Glad you found it. Please don't forget mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer, although you'll you have to wait 15 hours or so (48 hours after the question was posted) before the site will let you do that.
